# Поле для ввода текста в AlertDialog

Tags: android

Написал такой метод, для отображения диалогового окна. Как в окно добавить поле для ввода текста?

```
private void showDialog() {
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Новый рекорд");

    builder.setPositiveButton("Сохранить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Отмена", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    });

    builder.setCancelable(true);

    builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {

        }
    });

    builder.create();
    builder.show();

}
```

Comment: Нужно написать свою разметку для этого диалога. Если вопрос еще актуален, дайте знать - я помогу с кодом.

Comment: Спасибо, у меня получилось. Сделал разметку и указал ее через setView